# Extract multiple data rows out of a table in Firebird SQL using C# .NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, firebird, dapper

I can't find anything specific in the Firebird.NET documentaion, but I need to extract multiple specific data rows out of a table from my Firebird database. I later want to host the server and website formulars, where you can list all the employee with it's specific data fields which i want to choose manually.

The sql query would be:

```
SELECT employee_id, name, first_name, active_or_not
FROM t_personal
```

I can already make a query with a single return string inside the server-class using Dapper like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using Dapper;
using System.Data;
//the references i use


       public string SingleQuery(string commando)
    {
        try
        {
            String query = _festeVerbindung.Query<String>(commando).Single();

            return query;
        }
        catch (Exception oof)
        {
            return oof.Message;
        }
    }
```

Preferably i would like to extract them into a string array because i think this would be the best option to put it in an output web formular later, but if you have any better ideas i would appreciate it.

Comment: Checked the docs? https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebird%5D+dapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your query will work as you expect. You are returning one row of type string, but your SQL query is returning multiple fields. If you really want to return a string, then in the SQL statement you can concatenate the fields. But this would make dealing with the individual fields in the C# code harder. I would suggest something along the lines of below. I am illustrating 3 ways to do this. 1) with no where clause in the SQL, then another with a where clause and lastly converting the results to an array or strings. The snippet for the last i wouldn't recommend it, it is sloppy but it is there to show how you can transform the return set into an array of strings. If you need to really return an array of strings i would suggest using a CSV or JSON test serializer. Those packages call handle the anomalies you'd find when dealing with strings (like NULL or embedded commas, etc. ).

-HTH

```
   public class EmployeeRec
    {
        public int Employee_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string First_name { get; set; }
        public string active_or_not { get; set; }
    }
    public class QueryClass
    {

        public EmployeeRec[] ExecuteQueryNoWhereClause()
        {

            var sql = @"SELECT employee_id, name, first_name, active_or_not FROM t_personal";

            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection _festeVerbindung = Data.Connection.GetConnection("My Connectionstring"))
                {

                    var results = _festeVerbindung.Query<EmployeeRec>(sql).ToArray();

                    var activeOnly = results.Where(x => x.active_or_not == "Y");

                    return results;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception oof)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public EmployeeRec[] ExecuteQueryWithWhereClause(string activeFlag)
        {


            var sql = @"SELECT employee_id, name, first_name, active_or_not FROM t_personal WHere active_or_not = @ACTIVE_FLAG";

            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection _festeVerbindung = Data.Connection.GetConnection("My Connectionstring"))
                {

                    var results = _festeVerbindung.Query<EmployeeRec>(sql, new { ACTIVE_FLAG = activeFlag }).ToArray();

                    foreach (var item in results)
                    {

                    }
                    return results;


                }

            }
            catch (Exception oof)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public string[] ExecuteQueryReturnStringArray(string activeFlag)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> retArray = new List<string>();

            var sql = @"SELECT employee_id, name, first_name, active_or_not FROM t_personal WHere active_or_not = @ACTIVE_FLAG";

            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection _festeVerbindung = Data.Connection.GetConnection("My Connectionstring"))
                {

                    var results = _festeVerbindung.Query<EmployeeRec>(sql, new { ACTIVE_FLAG = activeFlag }).ToArray();


                    /*
                     * 
                     * There are better ways to do this, if you need to return a string array you should a Json or CSV text serializer like Servicestack.Text * 
                     * 
                     */
                    retArray.Add("employee_id, name, first_name, active_or_not");

                    foreach (var item in results)
                    {
                        retArray.Add(item.Employee_Id.ToString() + "," + item.Name + "," + item.First_name + "," + item.active_or_not);
                    }
                    return retArray.ToArray();


                }

            }
            catch (Exception oof)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The first solution showed me how to extract the result a into a list, which i rather needed than an array, so thank you!

Comment: But i don't really get these ACTIVE_FLAG things with the WHERE clause... what purpose does it have?

Comment: @MyNameIsLinuxx  In your question, you said "where you can list all the employee with it's specific data fields which i want to choose manually.". I presumed that you were asking about constraining the results returned based on specific data fields, meaning add a where clause to retrieve certain values. if that isn't what you were asking, then you can ignore. I just wanted to cover most basis.